# Adding additional records to existing relationship not working

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I am trying to add a new `Template` to an existing `Client`, but when I try to add the `Template` with an existing `ClientID`, it instead adds a new `Template` with a new `ClientID`, not tie the new Template to the existing `ClientID`

I use the following code to determine if the `Template` exists with the current `Client`. If not, I create a `Template` with the passed in existing `Client`

```
public Template GetCurrentTemplate(Client c, string TemplateName)
{
    using (var Context = new mssDBContext())
    {
        List<Template> CurrentTemplates = Context.Templates.Where(x =>  x.TemplateName == TemplateName && x.TemplateClient.Id == c.Id).ToList();
        if (CurrentTemplates.Count == 0)
        {
            Template t = new Template { TemplateName = TemplateName};
            t.TemplateClient = c;
            Context.Templates.Add(t);
            Context.SaveChanges();
            return t;
        }
        else
            return CurrentTemplates[0];
    }
 }
```

What I get is this :

[SQL Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v58CU.png)

What I would like is it to add the `Template` with the existing `ClientId` of 18, and not add a new `Client` with an Id of 19 and tie that to the `Template`.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Client c` instance you pass to your method is not tracked by the current instance of `Context` so it adds a new `Client` and binds template to it. There are few workarounds to the issue if you have `TemplateClient_Id` property set up on your `Template` entity you can just set it instead of assigning client by replacing :

```
t.TemplateClient = c;
```

with:

```
t.TemplateClient_Id = c.Id;
```

Otherwise you can attach `Client` instance to db context:

```
Context.Attach(c);
t.TemplateClient = c;
Context.Templates.Add(t);
Context.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: Thank you for this, I had seen Attach elsewhere but I dismissed it because my Context like you have written does not have a direct method for Attach?

EIther way, I added 'Context.Clients.Attach(c)' which seemed to work fine :)

Comment: @MajorSqueeze Yes, my code was for EF Core, it seems that EF6 and previous versions have `Attach` on `DbSet` level. Was glad to help!